# Salaht while being sick

Tags: salat

I missed fajr unintentionally while being very sick. I still pray the others as i am obliged to while being sick but missed fajr with no intention of it. Is it accounted as a sin on me? I will make up for it though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all brother Masha' Allah; very proud of you for being steadfast and concerned about your salat even when sick! I ask Allah Subhanahu Wa Ta'la to give you rapid recovery and good health.

In Islam you are judged based on your sincere intention, despite what the outcomes might be due to unexpected circumstances, based on [this](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:54) Hadith.

Moreover, if an individual misses any prayer of his prayers, either due to a slip from the memory (forgetting), or due to sleep (not intentionally sleeping on salat), then he should pray it when he recalls it, as that's the the only expiation, based on these Hadiths: [(1)](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:442), [(2)](https://sunnah.com/muslim:684d), and [(3)](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:597)

Comment: Al7amdulillah thank you brother!